# Do I own the code I write for analysis and applications using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: software, google

The terms of service for Google Earth Engine has the following sections:

> 7.4 Termination for Convenience. Customer may stop using the Services at any time with or without notice. Customer may terminate this Agreement for its convenience at any time on prior written notice and upon termination, must cease use of the applicable Services. Google may terminate this Agreement for its convenience at any time without liability to Customer.

> 7.5 Effect of Termination. If the Agreement is terminated, then: (i) the rights granted by one party to the other will immediately cease; (iii) Customer will delete the Software, any Application, any Customer Code, and any Customer Data; and (iv) upon request, each party will use commercially reasonable efforts to return or destroy all Confidential Information of the other party.

From [the TOS](https://earthengine.google.com/terms/), as of Sep. 26, 2021.

Section 7.4 states pretty clearly that Google may end the agreement at anytime for any reason, or no reason. Section 7.5 says that the customer must delete everything written that was used on Earth Engine. ie, all earth engine code and scripts. Does this mean that the customer has to delete *all* copies of their code? Including on personal computers and on sites like GitHub? And if that is true, does that essentially mean Google owns all that code written in the first place?

The [FAQ](https://earthengine.google.com/faq/) page seems to suggest otherwise with this statement. But there is no mention of "algorithm" anywhere on the official terms.

> Who owns the algorithms I write in Earth Engine and the results of my analyses?
> You do. The results of all analyses you perform are yours. All algorithms that you write with our API are yours. Here's the fine print.